# Constant Character Movement - AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, box2d, flashdevelop

How am I (am I?) suposed to make character movement with Box2D? I'll need the player to collide with the floor and others, however when it comes to moving him right or left, impulses aren't very handy. At least not what I have right now.

```
private function update(e:Event):void {
if (keys[Keyboard.RIGHT]) {
  impulse_x = 3;
  impulse_y = 0;
  mainChar.ApplyImpulse(new b2Vec2(impulse_x, impulse_y), mainChar.GetPosition());
} else {
  impulse_x = 0;
  impulse_y = 0;
  mainChar.ApplyImpulse(new b2Vec2(impulse_x, impulse_y), mainChar.GetPosition());
  }
}
```

How do I move my character in a steady pace, as opposed to what the code above does which is accelerate mainChar every update when the right key is being pressed.

EDIT:

So there was this code there but it's on c++ I think - I'd appreciate a translation, since it's so small, to AS3 ^^ as I have no idea what float is doing, syntax is a bit confusing to me.

```
b2Vec2 vel = body->GetLinearVelocity();
float desiredVel = 0;
switch ( moveState )
{
  case MS_LEFT:  desiredVel = -5; break;
  case MS_STOP:  desiredVel =  0; break;
  case MS_RIGHT: desiredVel =  5; break;
}
float velChange = desiredVel - vel.x;
float impulse = body->GetMass() * velChange; //disregard time factor
body->ApplyLinearImpulse( b2Vec2(impulse,0), body->GetWorldCenter() );
```

**In AS3**

```
switch (moveState)
    {
        case "RIGHT": desiredVel = 1.4; break;
        case "LEFT": desiredVel = -1.4; break;
        case "STOP": desiredVel = 0; break;
    }

velChange = desiredVel - mainChar.GetLinearVelocity().x;
impulse.x = velChange;
impulse.y = 0.0;
mainChar.ApplyImpulse(impulse, mainChar.GetWorldCenter());
```

(Should I delete the initial part of the post and leave the answer?)

Comment: You will have to check what the current speed is, and adjust the impulse you apply. This might help: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/constant-speed

Comment: I'll try to get around it as I can understand bits here and there but I'm writting this in AS3

Answer (score 0):

You should use a force. It's well described here: http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/forces